# Static type analysis with Python dicts

Tags: python, mypy

Can someone explain why this code, while valid, makes the mypy static analyser complain in multiple ways:

```
ranges = dict()
ranges['max'] = 0
ranges['services'] = []
ranges['services'].append('a')
```

Namely:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[<nothing>]", target has type "int")

error: "int" has no attribute "append"
```

If I simply add a type hint to the initial variable of `ranges: dict = dict()` it works fine.

I am confused about why the static analyser can't work this out by itself, especially as I am using the `dict` keyword to initialise the dict in the first instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionaries are usually used as keyed collections, the most important operation being to look up the value associated with an *arbitrary* key. Normally in a dictionary every key has the same type, and every value has the same type; if the values are heterogeneous then the expression `ranges[key]` wouldn't necessarily have a particular type (though you could represent it as a union).

In your code, the static analyser is trying to infer the type of your dictionary. The type it expects is of the form `Dict[K, V]` where `K` and `V` are yet to be determined. The first assignment `ranges['max'] = 0` gives information about both unknowns: `K` seems to be `str` and `V` seems to be `int`. So at this point, `ranges` is inferred as type `Dict[str, int]`.

The next two lines then give errors, because an empty list can't be used as a value in a `Dict[str, int]`, and values from a `Dict[str, int]` don't have an `append` method.

The explicit type annotation `ranges: dict = dict()` overrules the default behaviour by specifying that this is a heterogeneous dictionary, so that the values don't all have to have the same type. Given that information, the static analyser doesn't assume that because one of the values is an `int` that they all have to be `int`s.

Answer (score 4):

As you have not provided any annotations, `mypy` must try to infer the types. There are some choices it can make:

- `ranges = dict()` implies `range: Dict[Any, Any]`

  This would accept all of your code. It would also accept `ranges['services'].keys()` or any other operation since it erases all type information.
- `ranges['max'] = 0` implies `range: Dict[str, int]`

  This is what `mypy` picks. It rejects any values that are not integers, in specific your `list`.
- `ranges['services'] = []` implies `range: Dict[str, list]`

  This only accepts your `ranges['services']` field. The `ranges['max']` is invalid then, given that it is not `list`.
- `ranges['max'] = 0` *and* `ranges['services'] = []` implies `range: Dict[str, Union[int, list]]`

  This accepts assignment of the values. It rejects `ranges['services'].append('a')` since `ranges['services']` *might* be an `int`.

Basically, none of these work. With a plain `Dict[K, V]`, your code cannot be well-typed.

---

You can use [`typing.TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) to explicitly annotate `ranges`. Since `dict` is generally not restricted to static key-value pairs, `mypy` will not infer this by itself.

```
class Ranges(TypedDict):
    max: int
    services: List[str]

ranges: Ranges = dict()
```

Comment: Cool! `TypedDict` was added in 3.8 I think, but can be used in earlier versions with `from typing_extensions import TypedDict`